# Need a expression to pass as parameter in c#

Tags: c#, expression-trees

I am using a external DLL as reference.

When i try to consume a method its asking for a expression as a parameter to filter the results.

Its expecting the type as follows

`Expression<Func<Template, bool>>` type as a parameter.

The template type has name and group id as properties.

I am trying to create an expression that will check if the object is equal to the group id and if the name contains in a list of items as follows.

```
Expression<Func<Template, bool>> filterTemplatesDestination = tmplt =>
    stselectedTemplates.Contains(tmplt.Name) &&
    tmplt.TemplateGroupId == stDestGroupID;
```

But when i assign this expression to the method i am getting an exception. If i use just the group id to filter it work fine. The expression is throwing exception when i use condition to check if the name exists in my condition.

Comment: Can you provide code that works correctly (as you mention) and provide the  exception you are getting with the current sample?

Comment: The only exception it seems to me you can get from this code a nullReferenceExection on stselectedTemplates. Is it this one?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you get a NullReferenceException, I don't see any other possible exception in your code. Try this:

```
Expression<Func<Template, bool>> filterTemplatesDestination = tmplt =>
            (stselectedTemplates!= null && tmplt.Name!=null &&  stselectedTemplates.Contains(tmplt.Name)) &&
            tmplt.TemplateGroupId == stDestGroupID;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though your stselectedTemplate OR your tmplt.Name is null, I would take the Paolo Costa's answer and instead check for both null exceptions, but it may be better to debug your code and find exactly why those variables are returning null.